# Creating array with two unique entries for every entry from another array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to take an array like

```
[ "First.Package", "Second.Package" ]
```

and turn it into

```
[ "First.Package.ads", "First.Package.adb", "Second.Package.ads", "Second.Package.adb" ]
```

I've tried doing the following:

```
packages = [ "First.Package", "Second.Package" ]
files = []
packages.each do |package|
    files << (package << ".ads")
    files << (package << ".adb")
end
return files
```

Which does not do what I think it should do. I get:

```
First.Package.ads.adb
First.Package.ads.adb
Second.Package.ads.adb
Second.Package.ads.adb
```

I want:

```
First.Package.ads
First.Package.adb
Second.Package.ads
Second.Package.adb
```

Comment: A different approach `arr.flat_map { |str| [str+".ads",str+".adb"] }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`package << ".ads` mutates state of package. Use `+` for string concatenation in places like that, because it doesn't mutate state. It just returns new string(which is what you really want).

```
packages.each do |package|
    files << (package + ".ads")
    files << (package + ".adb")
end
```

this should work for your case

Comment: ...and to eliminate `files = []` and `return files`, write `packages.each_with_object(files) do |package, files|` followed by what you have.

Comment: You can also use `push` here which takes multiple arguments, like `files.push(package + ".ads", package + ".adb")`. Whether it's better to do so I'm not sure.

Comment: The problem is that additional code has to be written if an additional extension is added. Instead, the code should not care.

Answer (score 5):

```
packages = ["First.Package", "Second.Package"]
suffixes = [".ads", ".adb"]

packages.product(suffixes).map(&:join)
  #=> ["First.Package.ads", "First.Package.adb",
  #    "Second.Package.ads", "Second.Package.adb"]
```

Note that

```
packages.product(suffixes)
  #=> [["First.Package", ".ads"], ["First.Package", ".adb"],
  #    ["Second.Package", ".ads"], ["Second.Package", ".adb"]]
```

See [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product).

Comment: This is cool and you get my upvote, but using cartesian product on filenames may just be a little too clever for some teams...

Comment: I'd go with this. It will work if `packages` or `suffixes` get new elements without having to write more code.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
packages = %w(First.Package Second.Package)
extensions = %w(.ads .adb)
```

You could do it like this:

```
files = packages.map do |package|
  extensions.map do |extension|
    package + extension
  end
end.flatten
```

Comment: Consider using `flat_map` instead of the outer `map`. This will save you having to `flatten` at the end